# iOS >> Cloning a UI Object for Drag & Drop

Tags: ios, frame, uigesturerecognizer, addsubview, cloning

I wish to implement a Drag & Drop mechanism for UI Objects - UIImageViews, UIButtons, etc...
It should work as follow:

- Upon Pan Gesture event, the original UI Object should be cloned.
- The Cloned Object should respond to the Pan Gesture instead of the original one.
- There are other features, but they are not relevant to my question...

Now... I understand that I should create a new UI Object and add it as a Subview to the VC.view property and implement the Gesture Recognizer implementation to this Cloned Object.

Here are my questions:

- If my Original Object is a Subview of another View (like VC.view.subviews[2]) - How do I translate its FRAME from within this Subview to the VC.view FRAME?
- How do I make it become the responder of the Pan Gesture instead of the Original Object?

Answer (score 0):

**Q:** If my Original Object is a Subview of another View (like VC.view.subviews[2]) - How do I translate its FRAME from within this Subview to the VC.view FRAME?

**Ans:**

```
 CGPoint refPoint = [VC.view convertPoint:self.frame.origin fromView:VC.view.subviews[2]];
```

**Q:** How do I make it become the responder of the Pan Gesture instead of the Original Object?

**Ans:** You need to add pan gesture to cloned object as well

Comment: Thanks for answering... I did add Pan Gesture to the Original Object. It seems like it never gets into the method associated with this Gesture.